# after defining case for all enum values, compiler still says: "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c, gcc, enums, switch-statement, static-analysis

Writing a simple evaluate I came across a funny issue.

Given the code:

```
enum node_type {LEAF, NODE};

struct tree_elm_t {
  enum node_type type;
  union {
    struct tree_node_t node;
    struct tree_leaf_t leaf;
  } datum;
};

int parse_leaf(struct tree_leaf_t leaf);
int parse_node( struct tree_node_t node );
int parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree );

....

int parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree ) {
  switch( tree->type ) {
  case NODE: return parse_node(tree->datum.node);
  case LEAF: return parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf);
  }  
}
```

I was surprised to see that gcc is complaining about a missing control flow option :

```
example.c: In function 'parse_tree':
example.c:54: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

the flow problem can be solved by storing the return value, in a variable like so:

```
int parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree ) {
  int sum;
  switch( tree->type ) {
  case NODE: sum = parse_node(tree->datum.node); break;
  case LEAF: sum = parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf); break;
  }  
  return sum;
}
```

I do however find the original code alot cleaner, is there a way of making gcc accept the original code - (I want to static analysis to realize that my code is valid, and clean).

---

**EDIT:**

I might have been a bit unclear.

lets say I compile the following code :

```
int parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree ) {
  int sum;
  switch( tree->type ) {
  case NODE: sum = parse_node(tree->datum.node); break;
    // case LEAF: sum = parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf); break;
  }  
  return sum;
}
```

gcc will give me a warning:

```
example.c: In function 'parse_tree':
example.c:51: warning: enumeration value 'LEAF' not handled in switch
```

meaning that gcc has a sense of the options for values in the switch, and the fact that I hav commented out the LEAF case. This would imply that gcc also knows that when going though the switch every case is being examined. so why the statement:

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```

is it lack a lacking static analysis system in gcc - or a language feature?

Comment: Have you considered returning `0`?

Comment: Did you try adding a "default" statement to your switch that returns some error value, perhaps throws an exception if this is truly a circumstance that shouldn't happen?

Comment: Why make it return `int` if that's not your intention in the first place rather than `void`?

Comment: `if(NODE == tree->type) return parse_node(tree->datum.node); return parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf);`

Comment: The point is that my switch is taking into account EVERY single possible option, meaning that it does a return on EVERY single type of input... There is no need for a default

Comment: But what if `none` of the cases in switch are matched? Nothing is returned in this case. So, it has to ensure this case also.

Comment: @UchiaItachi  I think his point is to address the warning he would have to account for what is arguably an undefined value due to it being outside the domain of his enum, and to be completely honest I think its an interesting point.

Comment: @UchiaItachi: if you look at the `enum` you will see that all cases are covered - if they were not, the compiler would complain about that -- and that is the actual reason I don't like adding a default option - its not necessary.

Comment: @WhozCraig: exactly, The static analysis is detectng that I have covered all cases in my switch - it does however not detect that I have a return in every single case.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen I see your point, but it seems that according to the standard enums are just ints. So it's perfectly legal to say `tree->type = 42` and the compiler won't complain. Yes it's awkward but it's how things seem to work... a C++ compiler would complain a little more, though.

Comment: Which is precisely why a 'defaualt' with a thrown exception is the proper way to handle this.  Good point vanza.

Comment: @vanza: you are absolutely correct(or I think you are) the problem is with the fact that an enum is an int in disguise. and the switch wants to explore all options for the int.

Comment: I have renamed and retagged the question to make it even more clear what is being asked here :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler is complaining because all paths in your function's logic should return a value (as the prototype of this function prescribes):

```
int parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree ) {
    switch( tree->type ) {
    case NODE: return parse_node(tree->datum.node);
    case LEAF: return parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf);
    default: return 0;   // <-- problem solved
    }  
}
```

Compiler (like me in this answer) focuses rather on the syntax than semantics of your code.

And although you have defined `enum node_type {LEAF, NODE}`, your compiler doesn't want to rely on this constraint and accepts the possibility of `type` in `tree->type` statement having a different value from just `NODE` or `LEAF` anyway.

---

EDIT: I have tried this code:

```
enum node_type {LEAF, NODE}; 
struct node { enum node_type type; };

int parse_tree( struct node* n ) {
    switch( n->type ) {
    case NODE: return 1;
    case LEAF: return 2;
    }  
}

int main() {
  struct node n;
  printf("%d", parse_tree(&n));
  return 0;
}
```

on ideone and the result is following:
(gcc-4.8.1, compiled as "C") ~ http://ideone.com/b0wdSk : code is valid, outputs `2`
(gcc-4.8.1, compiled as "C++") ~ http://ideone.com/OPH5Ar : same as "C"
(gcc-4.8.1, compiled as "C99 strict") ~ http://ideone.com/ou71fe : invalid because of:

> error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

And to support [Martin Kristiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750186/martin-kristiansen)'s point about assigning any integral value to enum being valid, I have tried `struct node n; n.type = 7;` with the same code and with "C" but also with "C99 strict" the compiler doesn't complain at all. However "C++" gives:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘node_type’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: As odd as it sounds, the OP has an interesting question, but I'm not sure they understand just how so (or maybe they do). Per their code *all* defined values in their enum are covered in the switch. Therefore the "default" case you provide here would only happen if an *invalid* (and thus undefined) enum value was provided as a parameter. Its actually a more interesting question than I thought it was going to be.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I haven't noticed the `enum` before. I have edited my answer (see last paragraph), however it doesn't provide reasonable explanation *"why"* the compiler is not capable of doing so.

Comment: Exactly. You're not alone. When I first glanced at the question i was thinking.. "well duh, make sure all paths return.", but than I realized that if the input is in-fact conforming to the domain of `node_type`, he *is* returning all paths. And with that it suddenly because interesting (at least to me).

Comment: I like your little test(I do however wonder why it returns 2, that might be a random thing) @vanza gave, I think, the best answer on the control flow error - it stems from the fact that the node type can validly take any integer value, and not just the once defined in the enum. hence the fact that all options in the enum are covered does not mean that all values for the variable are covered.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen: Yes, you are right. Check my last edit :)

Comment: The test has undefined behavior before you hit any of the `case`s because `n->type` has an intermediate value.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the missing return warning with GCC but still get warnings if you are actually missing an `enum` `case`, stop the control flow after the `switch` statement but before the end of the function.
In C you can use `exit(int)`, `quick_exit(int)`, `_Exit(int)` or `abort()`. ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program#Program_termination))
In C++ there is the `throw` expression – with or without a proper exception as argument. ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw))
This also has the benefit of defined behavior in case the function gets called incorrectly.

Clang does not warn about the missing `return` btw.

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity come from the fact that in C `enum` types can store other values than the ones given in the type declaration, and that in any context, including your `switch` statement, an enumeration typed object evaluates to an `int`. You could avoid this warning with

```
  switch( tree->type ) {
  case NODE: return parse_node(tree->datum.node);
  default: return parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf);
  }
```

if you think that in further developement you'll add other cases. If not, you'd better go with a `bool` `isNode` or something like that.

Comment: I see where your going - my question does however originate from the fact that I am trying to write functional tree-folds on treelike datastructures, and I would like the static analysis in gcc to help me get it correct. Lets say I changed the form of my enum, then your code would compile without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add in a default case.

```
switch( tree->type ) 
{
    case NODE: return parse_node(tree->datum.node); break;
    case LEAF: return parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf); break;
    default :
        //perhaps throw exception here
        return 0;
}
```

Note that this situation probably doesn't need a switch statement, if/else if, is probably what you want.

Comment: the `return 0` would be jank-code since all cases are explored... end even worse, it would mean that in case I decided to add more options to my enum, the compiler would not complain about the lack of a case statement

Comment: Throwing an exception would mean finding the error in production - I would like to find as many errors as possible before putting my code on a cluster ;)

Comment: Umm, if you end up with a value sent to this function, would you rather throw an exception, or allow your program to run in an undetermined state?  You pick... personally, I'd prefer to catch the issue sooner, rather than later, independent of whether this happens in production or not.  Proper exception handling does not determine when bugs are found, this is done through testing.  Proper exception handling keeps your code from executing in an undetermined state, and to help you spot the source of errors...

Comment: Instead of throwing an exception in the default case, just do it _after_ the `switch`. That way you get the warnings for not handled `enum` values but overcome the warning about a missing `return` statement.

Answer (score -2):

Is there some reason this won't work? (added declarations):

```
void parse_leaf(struct tree_leaf_t leaf);
void parse_node( struct tree_node_t node );
void parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree );

void parse_tree( struct tree_elm_t* tree ) {
  switch( tree->type ) {
  case NODE: parse_node(tree->datum.node); break;
  case LEAF: parse_leaf(tree->datum.leaf); break;
  }  

}
```

Comment: It does work, the compiler does however complain about `control reaches end of non-void function` which is what troubles me.

Comment: okay, I see it now...  upvoting the other answer re: the default case

Comment: @Martin: This makes your comment about 'control reaches end of non-void function' no more valid.  This is not the issue with this answer.  It most certainly adresses your compilation issue.  But I agree, not the core issue at play.